# Getting an error when I log in with incorrect credentials

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So logging in works fine when I type in the correct username/password. However when I enter an incorrect username or password, it returns this error:

```
AttributeError: AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
def boxes_view(request):

    ...

    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

    form_login = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print('LOGGED IN')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form_login': form_login
    }

    return render(request, 'polls.html', context)


def register(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        print(form.non_field_errors)
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return redirect('/')


def user_login(request):
    form_login = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_login.is_valid():
        username = form_login.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form_login.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form_login.errors)
        print(form_login.non_field_errors)
        form_login = UserLoginForm()
    return redirect('/')


def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        current_emails = User.objects.filter(email=email)

        if current_emails.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("That email is taken")
```

**urls.py**

```
BV = views.boxes_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BV, name='news'),
    url(r'^user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^user_logout/', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),

]
```

**base.html** parent of polls.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'user_login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="loginWrapper">
        {{ form_login.username|placeholder:"username" }}
        {{ form_login.password|placeholder:"password" }}

        <input type="submit" value="login" style="margin-left: 10px"/>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'register' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="registerWrapper">
        {{ form.username|placeholder:"username" }}
        {{ form.email|placeholder:"email" }}
        {{ form.password|placeholder:"password" }}
        {{ form.confirm_password|placeholder:"confirm password" }}
        <input type="submit" value="register" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/draft1/draft1/views.py" in user_login
  108.         login(request, user)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  124.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  235.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user_login/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: always show in question full error message (Traceback) - not only last line. There can be other usefull information.

Comment: Added in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing quite a few strange things here. But the immediate problem is that you don't check whether authenticate actually succeeds.

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user:
    login(request, user)
else:
    # show an error
```

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem, thanks. What other 'strange things' are you seeing? The reason i've formatted the view like this is because I have the login and register forms on the homepage (accessible via javascript onclick, to prevent page refresh). So the login/register forms don't have their own URL.

Comment: Primarily that you don't return the form with errorsb if validation fails, but print the errors locally and then create a new empty form.